# ¿por qué no puedo acceder a los elementos de mi array en TypeScript?

Tags: array, angular, typescript

Estoy declarando un array de number, el cual se llena en un ciclo for, pero después, al tratar de acceder a los elementos de mi array me devuelve undefined.

```
labelsX : number[] = [];
```

Este es el ciclo con el cual lleno el array, lo hago de esta forma porque me interesa recuperar los últimos 5 registros en orden en mi array.

```
let aux = 4;
let j = resp.indicadores.length - 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    this.labelsX[aux] = this.indicatorsIn[j].generacion;
    this.dataIn[aux] = this.indicatorsIn[j].cantidad;
    aux -= 1;
    j -= 1;
  }
```

Y luego con este  ciclo intento recuperar los elementos en otro array, pero es cuando me devuelve undefined.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {      
  this.ELEMENT_DATA[i].anio = this.labelsX[i];
}
```

Así se ve mi array en consola:
console.log(labelsX)

[image: Así se ve el array en consola]

Comment: Prueba con añadir elementos al array usando push (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_array_push.htm)

Comment: @Orion Sí probé con el método push(), pero tampoco me deja acceder a los elementos después de llenarlo así

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podemos plantear la solución de diferentes formas.

1. De esta forma se puede realizar siempre y cuando los 2 ciclos sean consecutivos, de no ser así es mejor la forma 2

   ```
   let aux = 4;
   let j = resp.indicadores.length - 1;
   for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
     this.labelsX[aux] = this.indicatorsIn[j].generacion;
     this.dataIn[aux] = this.indicatorsIn[j].cantidad;
     aux -= 1;
     j -= 1;

     /**
      * Creamos un if validando que ya es el ultimo recorrido del for y así proceder a iniciar el for siguiente.
      */
     if (i === 4) {
       for (let k = 0; k < 5; ++k) {
         this.ELEMENT_DATA[k].anio = this.labelsX[k];
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. De esta forma lo que haremos para el ejemplo es distribuir el código en funciones diferentes, para así aprovechar el uso del async y el await.

   He ajustado el código para poder compartir un ejemplo funcional.

   Uso de [Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

   Uso de [async y await](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

```js
let labelsX = [];
let dataIn = [];
let ELEMENT_DATA = [];
const indicadores = [{
  generacion: 2017,
  cantidad: 1
}, {
  generacion: 2018,
  cantidad: 2
}, {
  generacion: 2019,
  cantidad: 3
}, {
  generacion: 2020,
  cantidad: 4
}, {
  generacion: 2021,
  cantidad: 5
}];

function ejecutarCicloUno() {
  labelsX = [];
  dataIn = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < indicadores.length; i++) {
    labelsX.push(indicadores[i].generacion);
    dataIn.push(indicadores[i].cantidad);
  }
}

function ejecutarCicloDos() {
  ELEMENT_DATA = [];
  for (let k = 0; k < labelsX.length; k++) {
    ELEMENT_DATA.push(labelsX[k]);
  }
}

window.onload = async function() {
  console.log('Procede a ejecutar el primer ciclo');
  await ejecutarCicloUno();
  console.log('Procede a ejecutar el segundo ciclo');
  await ejecutarCicloDos();
  
  console.log(ELEMENT_DATA[0]);
  console.log(ELEMENT_DATA[1]);
  console.log(ELEMENT_DATA[2]);
  console.log(ELEMENT_DATA[3]);
  console.log(ELEMENT_DATA[4]);
};
```

Espero logres comprender los ejemplos y alguna de las dos opciones se adapten mas a la forma que requieres, espero te sirva.

Saludos.

Comment: Fue de mucha utilidad tu respuesta, aunque no entiendo qué es lo que está pasando, la primer opción me sirvió para hacer lo que quería con mi array muchas gracias!